# How to check values from array list

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello i have a problem i can't solve.

I have a table with numbers and i want to check the numbers from the first array 'selection' with the numbers from the array 'final'. Final array are 7 random generated numbers. I tried for loop to get the only the numbers that match but doesn't work.

**Example**

if i press number 1 in the table it should generate 7 numbers in the first for loop then check if the array contain any numbers from selected and if it does to remove the ones that are not in selected.

```js
function func1(){
var random = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25];
var selection = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var numbers = [];
var extracted = [];
    for(i = 0;i < 7; i++){
    var randomPositionl = Math.floor(Math.random() * random.length);
    var final = random.splice(randomPositionl,1);
    numbers.push(final);
    console.log(final);
    }
  
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
    if (numbers.indexOf(selection[i]) > -1) {
    extracted.push(selection[i]);
    console.log(extracted);
    }
    }
    console.log(extracted);
}

function func2(){
  console.log(2);
}


function func3(){
  console.log(3);
}

function func4(){
  console.log(4);
}

function func5(){
  console.log(5);
}

function func6(){
  console.log(6);
}

function func7(){
  console.log(7);
}

function func8(){
  console.log(8);
}

function func9(){
  console.log(9);
}

function func10(){
  console.log(10);
}

function func11(){
  console.log(11);
}

function func12(){
  console.log(12);
}
```

```css
table {  
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  float:left;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  background-color: black;
}

td {
  border: 2px #a49e9b solid;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="15" cellspacing="15">
  <tr>
      <td onclick="func1()">1</td>
      <td onclick="func3()">3</td>
      <td onclick="func5()">5</td>
      <td onclick="func7()">7</td>
      <td onclick="func9()">9</td>
      <td onclick="func11()">11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td onclick="func2()">2</td>
      <td onclick="func4()">4</td>
      <td onclick="func6()">6</td>
      <td onclick="func8()">8</td>
      <td onclick="func10()">10</td>
      <td onclick="func12()">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what your program is trying to do. Let's say the user selects 3, 8, and 10. Do you want to generate seven "final" random numbers from that set, i.e. so that the "final" numbers might be, say, 8, 3, 3, 10, 3, 3, 8?

Comment: Each cell has function and when clicked it generates 7 random numbers and store them in array. With the second loop i want to check if the final array contains numbers from selection and if it does to remove the numbers that are not and store them in extracted.